# What is wrong with Path.CURVE3 and Path.CURVE4? Bézier curve messes up in a certain point

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-lab, bezier

I want to draw Bézier curves on JupyterLab with Python, and I am using MatplotLib in order to make a replica of a Lamborghini. The drawing has to be a faithful replica, so I used NumPy to bring the [Lamborghini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O825i.png) image as a background, as long as I can draw over it and manipulate its properties such as opacity. But no matter what I do, these very first points of the bumber just go crazy. I tried using Path.CURVE3 and Path.CURVE4, Path.STOP and also Path.LINETO in order to make the Bézier curve stop properly on a given point [(curve going crazy)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFrhO.png). I also tried making smaller curves, but I am not able to see what I want. I have to follow exactly the curves of the car. I used GIMP to extract the points I need.

Here is my code, actually, this situation is even more common than what I exposed here, it happens without NumPy image processing too. What are the rules of using CURVE objects? What are the limitations? What can make my curves go wrongly crazy?

```
import math
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.path as mpath
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Path = mpath.Path

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

bumper = mpatches.PathPatch(
    Path(
        [(22, 163), (12, 134), (13, 132), (30.6, 117.65), (43, 118)],
        [Path.MOVETO, Path.CURVE4, Path.CURVE4, Path.CURVE4, Path.CURVE4],
    ),
    fc="none",
    transform=ax.transData,
    color="green",
    lw=1,
)

ax.add_patch(bumper)

ax.set_title("Lamborghini Sián FKP 37", fontfamily="Tahoma", fontsize=22)
ax.set_aspect(1)

plt.xticks(np.linspace(0, 1180, 21), fontsize=10)
plt.yticks(np.linspace(0, 330, 9), fontsize=10)
plt.grid(color="gray", ls=":", lw=0.2)

lambo = plt.imread("Lamborghini Sian FKP 37 Right Side.png")

plt.imshow(lambo, alpha=0.35, extent=[0, 1180, 0, 330])

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (15, 6)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Research and documentation

So, after a period of research, I found [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/path_api.html#matplotlib.path.Path.MOVETO) in MatplotLib's documentation. Which made me figure out the meaning of quadratic `CURVE3` and cubic `CURVE4` curves from `Path.

`CURVE3` means you can only plot a curve with 2 given points, and `CURVE4` with 3 points. We have to keep in mind that:

**Start Point** is like putting the pencil on the paper, the very first point that begins a new trajectory. You achieve this by starting with `Path.MOVETO`;

**Control Point** is what really makes the curve. You can think of a perfectly straight rope between 2 given points. When the rope is pulled in some direction, it bends the rope creating the curve;

**End Point** is the very last point where you stop drawing and take the pencil off the paper.

---

## How to use `CURVE` attributes:

`Path.CURVE3` must be used with exactly 2 points:

- **1** Control Point;
- **1** End Point.

`Path.CURVE4` must be used with exact 3 points:

- **2** Control Points;
- **1** End Point.

I was struggling in a situation similar to this one:

```py
# I had to put a lot of points in a `verts` list like this
verts = [(x,y), (x,y), (x,y), (x,y), (x,y)]

# Following the previous path structure, I got a `codes` list like this
codes = [Path.MOVETO, Path.CURVE4, Path.CURVE4, Path.CURVE4, Path.CURVE4]
```

Note that in this example we have 5 points. When we are going to plot Bézier curves, we have to analyze whether it has to be a quadratic `CURVE3` or cubic `CURVE4` curve.

If you have 4 points, use `CURVE4`, if 3 use `CURVE3`. It is up to you on how you are going to organize a bigger figure in subdivided curves, you may compose a plot from various different curves.

If you have more than the limit of points, you have to **restart** the path regarding the size of the curve. Like this:

```py
verts = [(5, 30), (15, 55), (25, 15), (35, 40),  # 4 points
         (20, 10), (30, 0), (35, 10)],           # 3 new points, start a new curve

# `codes` means: the instructions used to guide the line through the points
codes = [Path.MOVETO, Path.CURVE4, Path.CURVE4, Path.CURVE4, # Begin the curve
         Path.MOVETO, Path.CURVE3, Path.CURVE3]              # Start a new one

bezier1 = mpatches.PathPatch(
    Path(verts, codes),
    # You can also tweak your line properties, like its color, width, etc.
    fc="none", transform=ax.transData, color="green", lw=2)
```

[image: plot example]

**IMPORTANT:** if you are plotting a single long curve, when a part of the line is completed, you have to start the continuation of the line by the immediate last point, this will give you a continuous curve. That is what I discovered, I hope this helps someone.